# How to pass variable in curl API?

Tags: curl

I need some help I am not much of a coder :-) ANy help will be appreciated:

what I am trying to do is be able to run this script to pull specific data from a given date so I can then parse with the script and recall the parsed file to execute the next command.

Where I am currently stuck is $no_vm_scan_since doesn't seem to pass the date stored in $no_vm_scan_since to the curl command.

So I keep getting an error: `curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL`

script is as follows:

```
no_vm_scan_since="$(date -v-7d +%Y-%m-%d)"

echo $no_vm_scan_since

curl -u "username:pass" -H "X-Requested-With: curl" -X GET "https://api.com/api/2.0/fo/asset/host/?action=list&no_vm_scan_since=$no_vm_scan_since" > expire
```

Comment: How are you running this script?

Comment: I am on a mac; the script runs and executes:  sh name.sh